# What is the time complexity for this loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

How can we find the time complexity for this loop

```
int c = 0;
int j = 1;
while (j< n^3) {
  c+=1;
  System.out.println(c);
  j=j*4;
}
```

Comment: `^` is xor and not exponentiation as you probably intended, but funnily enough that doesn't change the time complexity here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every time j is multiplied by 4 we can say after every iteration it can be written as :

```
1, 4, (4^2), ..., (4^k)
```

Now for loop to be false, `(4^k) >= n^3`

```
4^k >= n^3
k = log(n^3) to the base 4
```

You can further simplify it to:

`3log(n) to base 4` and remove 3 as we do for constants.

```
k = log(n)
```

This should be the complexity of your loop.

Comment: Can we do it with log base 2?,                   Since every time j is multiplied by 4 we can say after every iteration it can be written as: 1,2^2 ,   2^4, 2^(2*k) ?

Comment: yes you can further simplify this solution, as log(n) base 4 -> (log(n) base 2)/(log2 base 2) using the property of log. then you can drop the denominator as it is a constant term.